# Suppressing Data Labels in Excel if #N/A Value

Tags: excel-formula

In Excel, I have a column chart with data labels. The source data consists of formulas which occasionally result in #N/A values. Currently, the data labels for #N/A points are literally displayed as "#N/A". Is there any way I can have Excel suppress the data label altogether if the underlying value is #N/A? If I use =IFERROR(A1,""), then that displays a 0 so that does not work.

Comment: try `=IFERROR(A1,NV())`

Comment: @MarcoGetrost - `NV()` function?

Comment: Thanks, but the =NV() function produces a #NAME? error for me.

Comment: @Jeeped Sorry, I'm using the German Excel and there the `=NV()` function is the equivalent ti the `=NA()` function in english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the number format of the labels to not display anything when it interprets a zero, if you don't want to display anything even when the formulas evaluate to zero.

There is a very in depth discussion of techniques such as this here:

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/568361-charts-data-labels-using-%3Dna.html

Comment: The problem with this method is that some of my actual values are "0", and I do not want to suppress those valid 0's.

Comment: OK I found a solution using the link you provided. I simply have to set all my actual "0" values to "0.000000001", then my =iferror(A1,"") cells are the only ones that are 0 so I can use the 0;;; number format to suppress all 0's.

Answer (score -2):

I had this problem as well and found the easiest solution is to

1. duplicate the chart data fields
2. add those as new series to the chart data
3. change the series chart type for the new fields to a line chart with no line and no marker
4. show the data labels only for those new fields.

(column charts will show #N/A, line charts do not).